# Spring Boot add role to DB only if unique

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am constructing a spring boot application which has a one to many relationship between users and roles entities.

Users:

```
@Entity //Marks class as an entity for JPA
@Table(name="users") //Gives the table a name
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id //Marks variable as id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
```

Roles:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="roles") //Gives the table a nam
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    String role;
```

I am trying to make it so that when a user is saved into the db using the repository save functionality using the CrudRepository...

```
void addUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user); //adds new user to db.
    }
```

...The user is added into the database and the given role type is also attached to the object when sending over the following Json object:

```
{
        "name": "John Hancock",
        "phoneNumber": "555-5555-555",
        "address": "address...",
        "email": "John@gmail.com",
        "password": "adhajisdhakjsd",
        "roles":[{
            "role": "Admin"
        }]
    }
```

The following code does work by adding the USER into the db with the attached ROLE, however adding additional users with the same role, adds a new identical ROLE row inside the database.

Question: Is there a way to make it that a newly added user just uses the already existing with ROLE without adding a new row?

Comment: How are you populating the `Role` to the `User` object passed on the `addUser` method? If the `Role` contains the `id` it wouldn't replicate the role but rather re-use what's already on the database, on the other hand, if you send a `Role` object without id it will store the role again, it would be good to add a `unique constraint` to the `role`.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero The `Role` to `User` object passed to the addUser method is populated by the `CrudRepository<Role,Integer>` which contains a `save()` function which does the DB populating. After adding a `@Column(unique=true)` as suggested resulted in me receiving the following error: 

"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_g50w4r0ru3g9uf6i6fr4kpro8]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

Comment: That exception is expected, but I'm not completely following how you're adding the roles, you can't save the role every time otherwise you'll have this duplication on every insert.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero The role has a relationship with the user object and is added into the db using a predefined `save()` function supplied with the `CrudRepository<Role,Integer>` extension on the `UserRepository inteface`. what I am wondering is how can I make it so the `role` is added to the shared `user_role` table if the role already exists inside the database.

Comment: You need to manually map the role to the user object, otherwise, it will duplicate the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can make "role" primary key. But better not to do it on this level.

You can map the role at the mapping stage.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: do what exactly?